# How to loop through a text box list created in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need some help.

I have created a list of text boxes and now I want to access them with a for loop.
I want to hide/show the text boxes when I need.

I have created the list as follows,

```
public List<TextBox> at = new List<TextBox>(); 
public Form1()
{
Initialise Component();

at.Add(textBox65);
at.Add(textBox66);
at.Add(textBox67);
at.Add(textBox68);
}
```

I need to hide these using a for loop.I have a total of 68 textboxes starting from 1.
any help would be appreciated so much.
Thank you!

Comment: `foreach (TextBox box in at) {...}` or `for (int i = 0; i < at.Count; ++i) {TextBox box = at[i]; ...}`

Comment: Thank you so much sir. But how do I hide them each using the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for-each loop do the following

```
foreach (TextBox box in at) {
box.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Really appreciate your help. God bless you.